# Facing issue while installing pycaret in airflow DAG?

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies, regression, pycaret

We are facing issues while installing pycaret library in airflow dag using Bootstrap file.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pycaret==2.3.8
```

Error:

```
Collecting pyod
  Downloading pyod-1.0.8.tar.gz (149 kB)
     150.0/150.0 kB 9.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
```